# How to change the referenced entity field value?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a node that has a node reference to another content type. What I want is to update the referenced node field value on updating the node;

Let me clarify the issue.

For example I have a node of type "Basic Page" which having a relationship to a node of type "Article". I want to sync fields in two node let say I have a name field(Text) in both nodes. 
On updating  basic page node I want to populate the referenced node Name field with that of the value in the basic page node Name field. How can I do that?

This is what I have done so far:

1. Event - After updating existing content.
2. Condition - Content is of type Basic page.
3. Action - Fetch entity by id(id from the entity reference field).
4. Action - Set a data value .

I am stuck at the fourth step I can't select the name field of the entity fetched in the data selector.

How can I populate the referenced node field with the value of the blog page node field?

Note: This is just for example In real case I want to map multiple fields from one node to another.

This is the exported rule:

```
{ "rules_on_updating_basic_page_nodes" : {
    "LABEL" : "On updating Basic Page nodes",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "page" : "page" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "node", "id" : [ "node:field-article:nid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a Condition to the rule of the class:
"Entity has field", and then a whole bunch of the referenced fields of the entity will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make it call a Rule Component as you need to specify conditions before the available options in the Rules interface will be available.

As you're fetching an entity these options won't be available.

Comment: What you meant by "call a Rule Component". Is there any solution to make it work. I found a solution by adding custom PHP code inside the rule action for loading a node and make the changes and then saving it, all this is done by manual coding. Is that the only solution? Is there any alternative method?

Comment: Components are stand-alone Rules configuration that can be called from reaction rules, other modules and also programmatically from custom code https://www.drupal.org/node/1300024